# Tens of thousands of failed/denied SSH login attempts

Tags: server, ssh, login, lamp, log

Recently a few friends and I came up with an idea for an app. To facilitate the creation of it, we set up LAMP on an Ubuntu Server 12.04. This box is running from my home. We've set up 3 user accounts. I'm still pretty new to Linux, but I have a bit of experience from using Ubuntu on my own box.

Today I was playing around with SSH and looking at the logs (I need to learn how to read that information to know how the server is performing, right?) and I saw the strangest thing.

In /var/log/auth.log and /var/log/auth.log.1 I saw a bunch of failed login attempts for 'root' and a few usernames I'm not familiar with. I looked over them and for as far as I can see no user has been authenticated except for the actual users on the system. A lot of the IP-addresses listed seem to be from Russia.

As of now this server contains nothing but a vanilla Ubuntu Server with LAMP, but even so, with the following command:

```
sudo grep -i fail /var/log/auth.log | wc -l
```

I get 3412 as a result. This seems very excessive for a server that has been up since April 8th. It gets worse, because running the above command on auth.log.1 returns 23075 (!!!!) results.

It seems obvious that people are trying to break into the server. Not that it contains anything of value, but once we start making progress on the app we wouldn't want our intellectual property stolen.

Should I be worried? And what can I do about it?

**EDIT:**

I found some very useful information [here](http://blog.philippklaus.de/2010/02/analyse-illegal-ssh-login-attempts/) and this allowed me to run a script that splits and sorts all the invalid passwords and invalid users that tried to log in. May come in handy to someone who ended up here through Google!

Comment: Don't expose your computer directly to the Internet. Bot nets will be constantly trying to break into any open ports in this manner, be it SSH or HTTP. You need to firewall your computer and network.

Comment: Thank you. I'll do that, and let google be my friend. Got any tips, or can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: And, do that fake account exist?

Comment: No, none of them do. It seems whoever (or whatever bot) is trying to log in is doing so with usernames like 'babu' and 'ashrae'. Weirdly specific. There's also some root login attempts but I believe Ubuntu disables that account in favor of sudo.

Comment: @dobey in general I agree, but sometime you want the access to your computer from anywhere... so you have to bit the bullet. See my answer for counter-measures.

Comment: @Rmano That's what OpenVPN is for. Open up a single port through your router, VPN in, access everything on your local network, without exposing everything to the world.

Comment: @dobey well it's what I do --- simply my openVPN is sshd itself. It is the only open port, and then I connect everywhere with -L and -R port redirection, using public/private keys pairs... is OpenVPN intrinsically safer than sshd?  Nevertheless, I will study openVPN sometime --- thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to harden an SSH server?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2271/how-to-harden-an-ssh-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening a lot to me too. There are a lot of script kiddies trying brute force attacks against your SSH server.

My solution till now was to install [DenyHosts](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/), but seems that it will be not supported in 14.04; the next best solutions seems to be [Fail2Ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). Links and  more information in [Package denyhosts in Ubuntu Trusty Tahr is deleted: temporary or forever?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433924/package-denyhosts-in-ubuntu-trusty-tahr-is-deleted-temporary-or-forever)

In that answer, bodhi.zazen pointed to this highly recommended page: https://web.archive.org/web/20190828185822/http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/SSH_security

Comment: Great, I'll mark it as solved! Thanks for the information, I'll have a look.

Comment: What about a firewall?  That won't exactly help much for ssh, but it's important on a server.

Comment: @Seth Well, if you have a server you can't block incoming connection. At least, not on the services you want to offer. So security is important; the article on hardening the server by bodhi.zazen is worth reading.