# Unable to block port 25

Tags: 16.04, iptables

I have a dedicated server with an LXC container on it. The container has IP: 11.22.33.44.

I want to block outgoing port 25 of this container, so that the container cannot send out email.

From the host machine (Ubuntu 16.04), i use the following commands:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 25 -s 11.22.33.44 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -s 11.22.33.44 -j DROP
```

However, from inside the container, i still can telnet to port 25 of another server

```
bash-4.1# telnet mysite.com 25
Trying 64.14.157.215...
Connected to mysite.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 phoenix.mysite.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
```

Previously, i used debian 8 as the OS for my host machine, and it work great, but in ubuntu 16.04, i may miss some important steps to make it work.

Could anyone help me point out what is wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: `iptables` is used for incoming connections, once you've stopped the mail server on the "host server", `telnet` is used for outgoing connections. Or I don't understand the question.

Comment: @waltinator I'm trying to block outgoing block port 25, so that from the container the user cannot send out email

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use ufw on the host machine?
You could do for example

`sudo ufw deny proto tcp from 10.0.0.1 to any port 25`

This should disallow tcp from 10.0.0.1 to any IP address on port 25.

You can find more examples here: [How to deny an ip address from connecting to my system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/411870/how-to-deny-an-ip-address-from-connecting-to-my-system)

Comment: From what i see, that link is to prevent incoming connection. Anyway i have tested your code, but i still can telnet port 25 and can still send out email from the container

Comment: Please try `sudo ufw deny out proto tcp from 11.22.33.44 to any port 25`

Comment: It still not working :(